# Should we use DiffUtils over notifyDataSetChanged all the time, or there is case where notifyDataSetChanged perform better?

Tags: android

Recently, as our app data grows, we encounter ANR during diff computation by using `DiffUtils`.

We solve the issue by

1. Optimizing `areContentsTheSame` computation, by redefining equals definition of 2 objects.
2. Place `DiffUtil.calculateDiff` execution in the user thread.

---

I know `DiffUtils` will be extremely handy, compared to `notifyDataSetChanged`, especially in the following case

1. There are total 100 items, and 10 items will be visible on `RecycleView`
2. If we are using `notifyDataSetChanged`, all 10 items will be redrawn
3. If we compute `DiffUtil.calculateDiff` 100 items, only affected & visible items will be redrawn
4. This assumes (3) is faster than (2)

But, I was pondering, what if the following case?

1. There are total 100000 items, and 10 items will be visible on `RecycleView`
2. If we are using notifyDataSetChanged, all 10 items will be redrawn
3. If we compute DiffUtil.calculateDiff 100000 items, only affected & visible items will be redrawn
4. Is it possible, that `DiffUtil.calculateDiff` will cost more than redrawing all visible items on `RecyclerView`?

I was wondering, instead of going all-in into `DiffUtils`, should we

```
if number of items > N {
    notifyDataSetChanged
} else {
    DiffUtils
}
```

Should we use `DiffUtils` over `notifyDataSetChanged` all the time, or there is case where `notifyDataSetChanged` perform better?

If that is so, how can we decide when to use `DiffUtils`, and when to use `notifyDataSetChanged`?

Comment: Running diffutil in main thread is not recommended in general, you can use `ListAdapter` which defers it to a background thread. It should work at decent speed when you have like 100 or 1000 items, for larger lists I'd say it doesn't matter since conceptually at this point you'd be implementing paging to break it into more sensible pieces.